# "tee" allows us to redirect output from a command - is there any simple way to output the command string being run itself too?

Tags: linux, unix

When looking at log files many times I wonder what options/parameters did I use when running a given command that generated this log file.

Is there any simple way to output the command string being run itself too into stdout to be redirected into the log file at the top of the file?

Comment: `echo this_is_my_command >>logfile`?

Comment: Besides the already mentioned `set -x`, you can create a wrapper like `verbose(){ printf '>>'; printf ' %s' "$@"; echo; "$@"; }`, then `verbose cmd arg | tee logfile` (unlike `set -x`, this will print the commands to *stdout*, not stderr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can echo the command, tee it to a file, pipe it to `sh`, then append the output to the file with `tee -a myfile`:

```sh
echo "ls -la" | tee myfile | sh | tee -a myfile
```

On stdout, you see just the output of the command, but in `myfile`, the first line is `ls -la` and the following lines contain the output of the command.

Comment: Wow - some crafty maneuvers - surprised that mature platforms like unix/linux don't have a simpler way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In the script that write to the log file, use `set -x`, which prints into STDERR the commands that are executed. Use `set +x` to reset to the default behavior (no printing of the commands).

Example:

Script `test.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "INFO: test log message 1"
set -x
echo "INFO: test log message 2"
set +x
echo "INFO: test log message 3"
```

Run the script:

```
./test.sh 1>test.log 2>&1
```

Output in `test.log`:

```
INFO: test log message 1
+ echo 'INFO: test log message 2'
INFO: test log message 2
+ set +x
INFO: test log message 3
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[Debugging Bash scripts](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)